# How to do find and replace in vim with

Tags: regex, vim

I am having set of records like this

```
Affiliate.create(email: 'example@example.com', name: 'xxx', mobile: '99999999 ', company_name: 'Exxample', approved:true, city_currently_residing_in: 'Indore', affiliate_occupation_id: AffiliateOccupation.find_by(name: 'Chartered Accountant (CA)').id, user_id: User.find_by(email: 'example@example.com').id
```

How do I replace

```
Affiliate.create(email: 'whateverstring',
```

with whitespace.

I tried

```
%s/Affiliate.create(email: '[a-z]',/
```

Comment: I think you gotta add /gci in the end. And probably escape the opening parenthese (not sure about this one, try it both ways) as well as the dot. Like this: %s/Affiliate\.create\(email: '[a-z]',/ /gci or %s/Affiliate\.create(email: '[a-z]',/ /gci

Comment: You're basically only missing the multiplicity item (`*` or `\+`) on the `[a-z]` (which can also be written as `\l`). For the whitespace, do you mean a fixed number or exactly as many as replaced!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
:%s/Affiliate\.create(email: *'[^']*',/ /
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/Affiliate\.create(email: '[^']\+', /\=substitute(submatch(0), '.', ' ', 'g')/
```

will substitute with the equivalent amount of whitespace. If you need fixed amount of whitespace, Avinash Raj's or anubhava's answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

if you are in vim, you don't need do substitution, do it in this way:

```
g/^Affiliate\.create(email:/norm! 0df,
```

### note

the above line will **delete** the `Affili....` part, not **replace them with same number of spaces.** If you want to replace them into whitespaces. (leave that part as empty, but not removing):

```
 g/^Affiliate\.create(email:/norm! 0vf,r (space at the end)
```

Comment: Why is `:s` not a Vim way?

Comment: +1 for a creative solution that handles the whitespace-fill beautifully

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code,

```
:%s/Affiliate\.create(email: '[^']*',/ /
```